# trouble creating arrays based of the sizeof another array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array in php like

```
$hours(1,5);
```

what i want is create arrays based on the sizeof hours array which is in this case is 2
nw after creating two array i want to add elements in these arrays such that.
Array1 should have elements like

```
    Array1(60);
```

and Array2 have elements like

```
    Array2(60,60,60,60,60);
```

nw i have another array $remaining_time which has values like

```
    Remaining_array(30,43);
```

what i want to do is push the values of the remaining array in both the above above arrays

my desired output is

```
   Array1(60,30);
```

and

```
   Array2(60,60,60,60,60,43);
```

i tried achieving this but the result was not according to my liking

below is my code
....

```
   function time_array($totalMinutes)        //totalminutes(90,343);
{

foreach ($totalMinutes as $value) 
{
$result=$value/60;                           //Result(1.5,5.71)
$y=explode(".",$result);
$hours=$y[0];                               //hours(1,5)
$hrz[]=$hours;
$hours_mins=$hours*60;                     //hours_mins(60,300);
$remaining_mins[]=$value-$hours_mins;      //remaining_mins=(30,43)
                                           //(90,343)-(60,300)
}
for ($j=0; $j<sizeof($hrz) ; $j++)         //creating two arrays
{ 
    $hours_array[$j]=array();
    foreach ($hrz as $hr) 
    {
        for ($i=0; $i <$hr; $i++) 
        { 
            array_push($hours_array[$j],60);
        }
    }
    for($t=0;$t<sizeof($remaining_mins);$t++)
    {
        array_push($hours_array[$j],$remaining_mins[$t]);
    }
}

        print_r($hours_array);  
}
```

the output of my code was

```
        array(
         [0]=>array 
                  (
                  [0]=>60,
                  [1]=>60,
                  [2]=>60,
                  [3]=>60, 
                  [4]=>60, 
                  [5]=>60,
                  [6]=>30,
                  [7]=>43,
                   ),
         [1]=>Array 
                   (
                  [0]=>60,
                  [1]=>60,
                  [2]=>60,
                  [3]=>60, 
                  [4]=>60, 
                  [5]=>60,
                  [6]=>30,
                  [7]=>43,

                    ),
         )
```

my desired result is

```
     Array1(60,30);
                 and
     Array2(60,60,60,60,60,43);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple php function [`array_fill`](http://php.net/array_fill):

```
$hours = array(1, 5);
$value = 60;
$ar1 = array_fill(0, $hours[0], $value);
// print_r shows `Array ( [0] => 60 )`

$ar2 = array_fill(0, $hours[1], $value);
// print_r() shows `Array ( [0] => 60 [1] => 60 [2] => 60 [3] => 60 [4] => 60 )`

// after that
$more_items = array(30, 43);
$ar1[] = $more_items[0];
// print_r() shows `Array ( [0] => 60 [1] => 30 )`

$ar2[] = $more_items[1];
// print_r() shows `Array ( [0] => 60 [1] => 60 [2] => 60 [3] => 60 [4] => 60 [5] => 43 ) `
```

Comment: sir i have a issue

Comment: the thing is i want to create arrays based on the sizeof hours array

Comment: hours array is populating dynamically

Comment: and so is the $more_items

Comment: So use `for` or `foreach` like you do originally

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays

```
Remaining_array(30,43);
Array1(60);
Array2(60,60,60,60,60);
```

Take first element from remaining array and push into Array1

```
array_push($array1,$Remaining_array[0]);
```

Take last element from remaining array and push into Array2

```
array_push($array2,end($Remaining_array));
```